# Extending PiCam with CSI to HDMI issue

Tags: hdmi, raspicam

(Links to Amazon are not affiliated, or endorsed, but strictly to show the devices used)

I wanted to extend my PiCam distance from my RPI3B, and purchased a CSI-to-HDMI module ( [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B06XDNBM63/re](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XDNBM63) ... UTF8&psc=1 ) and a long HDMI cable ( https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B009A ... UTF8&psc=1 ), but when viewing the PiCam output, it was a magenta screen, with ghost-like movement, unrelated to where the camera was aimed. After swapping out various components, it ended up being the HDMI cable. Another HDMI cable that I had handy, worked just fine, with a perfect image. The cable that worked, isn't anything special, that I'm aware of, but it's not very long, and too bulky and inflexible to go ahead and just use it. Was the particular cable I bought too long? Is there a max length (I haven't found one for this use)? Is there some particular spec for HDMI that I should look for when I buy a new one, that will work with my PiCam?  I've had similar issues between computers and monitors, where one HDMI would work, and another wouldn't.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps you should try researching categories of HDMI cable (by which I mean, just enter "types of HDMI cable" into an internet search engine), and then (since there are, in fact, different standard categories), you have the great advantage of already having one which works and one which doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Second your link (https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B009A) showing **"Page Not Found"**, but if it is shorter than 25 ft, length shouldn't be a problem. Missing color is a strong indicator of that one of the pins is faulty.
Try to connect with that cable knowingly working HDMI devices (PC to TV e.g.). That should tell if cable is working.
Also, simplest HDMI should work with at least at 720p or 1080 interlaced.